# TIdIOHandler.ReadBytes メソッドの戻り値

Tags: c++

英語版のStack Overflowにて ReadBufferの代用について質問 した際に、回答者さんからサンプルコードを教えてもらった時にReadBytesメソッドの戻り値が1バイトを戻すことを知りました。

もらったサンプルコード

```cpp
System::Byte __fastcall ReadByte();

template<typename T>
void __fastcall Populate(T& obj, TIdIOHandler* ioh) {
    System::Byte* p = (System::Byte*) &obj;
    for(unsigned count=0; count<sizeof(T); ++count, ++p)
        *p = ioh->ReadByte();
}

BKUK_PACKET Pkt;
Populate(Pkt, Context->Connection->IOHandler);
```

このReadByteというメソッドの戻り値が1byte単位で出てくるということが、[TIdIOHandler.ReadBytes Methodのヘルプ](http://ww2.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdIOHandler_ReadBytes@TIdBytes@Integer@boolean.html)では記載されていないと思うのですが、Indy10のヘルプサイトにReadBytesの戻り値に関する情報は記載されているサイトや確認方法はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

メソッド名と(リンク先の)ドキュメントでパラメータの説明を読む限り、**パラメータで指定したバイト数を読み取るメソッド**で、指定が無ければ(明記されてないけど)1Byteずつ読み取る、という事ではないでしょうか。

> ```
> procedure ReadBytes(
>     var VBuffer: TIdBytes; 
>     AByteCount: Integer; 
>     AAppend: boolean = true
> ); virtual;
> ```
>
> AByteCount:   Number of bytes expected in the read request.

Comment: 解説頂きありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

回答に出ている ReadByteとReadBytesは別のメソッドです。
そしてReadByteメソッドについてはヘルプに乗っていません。

GitHubのソースの[IdIOHandler.pas](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/blob/master/Lib/Core/IdIOHandler.pas#L1356)を見るとReadByteは内部で1Byteだけ読むようにReadBytesを呼び出しているようです。